# ramping up on sys admin through certification

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I'm from a development background but have been hired as an all-round IT person to a company of 150 people approx. The expectation is that I will step into the sys admin, network admin and hardware support roles all of which have been outsourced to date. In addition I will be trying to do as much development as possible.
I'm not afraid of the challenge (I've been around for a while) and there will be more in-house help down the line. But I need to ramp up on a lot of stuff. The transition timeline hasn't been decided.
As part of growing into the role I am thinking of taking the following certification:
1) MCTS 70-662 - Exchange 
2) MCTS 70-640 - ActiveDirectory 
3) MCTS 70-669 - Virtualization for Windows Server R2 
4) Comptia Network+

Q. Are these certifications (or at least covering the ground) worthwhile? If so, are there other certifications that I should be thinking about if I am responsible for Exchange 2010, Win Server 2008 R2 and other applications running in a virtualized environment?

Comment: I came from a background of 10 years on the job experience before I decided to do the exams. Taking the exams didn't actually teach me a great deal but what it did do was cross the Ts and dot the Is on a number of important subjects. If you're not all that bothered for getting the certification, I would still recommend reading the books!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably save a lot of money just by jumping in and using MSDN / Google as and when it's required. Don't underestimate your own abilities - you don't need the paper unless you're trying to make your CV look good.

Answer (score 1):

With your experience you'll probably have no trouble reviewing the materials and writing/passing the exams.  The certs are a good review and you'll probably learn a thing or two along the way.  The certifications are handy to have for your next job since you're already in and have established yourself in your current job.  There are a tonne of good resources out there to help fill out what you have, if needed, and learn new things too.  Whatever way you decide to go, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Technet has some great material that is equally as good as the books. I am always browsing Technet on Exchange, Hyper-V and Active Directory.